# What regular expression can I use to extract the value of a query-string parameter?

Tags: regex, delphi

This is my string: `href="/store/apps/details?id=SomeString&`.

How can I extract the **SomeString** with PerlRegEx? I'm using Delphi XE2.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: Does it matter? Delphi XE2

Comment: Yes, since each language can have a different regex flavour

Comment: use the regex: `(SomeString)`

Comment: @Kermia: it matters a lot, since regex flavors vary from a language to the next.

Comment: Why not use the built in regex library?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is it available in XE2? I didn't know that:)

Comment: Was introduced in XE. I think it's just a wrapping up of the library you are using.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a dedicated library routine rather than regex?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hmm, I don't know, What is the difference?

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
href="/store/apps/details\?id=([^&"]*)
```

SomeString will be captured in group 1.

Comment: You're missing something: `<a href="foo?id=barbaz"> this gets captured too.`

Comment: @ctn It doesn't work. The String `href="/store/apps/details?id=` is a constant. and must exist in the string

Answer (score 2):

use the regex: \bid=.*(&)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex

```
[?&]id=([^a]*)&?
```

http://rubular.com/r/6ivQNNBLxP

mind you depending on what is and is not an allowable input, just about any conceivable reg-ex can be tricked

Answer (score 1):

You can use : `.*id=\([^&]*\)&`

Depending on the language you are using, you might find tools cleaner than regexps to perform this task.